# Programmatic click event for Paper JS

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events, paperjs

I'm attempting to fire a vanilla JavaScript [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) that will be received by [Paper JS](http://paperjs.org/). I have an HTML canvas `drawing-canvas` that has been `paper.setup`. Here is my current attempt:

```
const drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('drawing-canvas');
drawingCanvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
    buttons: 1,
    clientX: 1153,
    clientY: 550,
    screenX: 1153,
    screenY: 621,
}));
```

Firing this from the console does not trigger my `Layer` mouse events.

[Here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/lVLfa8IwEP5XQl9aoZbWKYOOvUwcDDYYKGyiPsT0qlljIk2qc+L/vkvj7xe3Qpved999uTu+rSfpArzU6xdg2NwLPaYyG69oSQx8G/JIJKzJu+LSDDAOtuNyLAk+SwulZNSJQ9KJJ+EBZ0oasBl/MIdDpInKicG4rqqV/WNFzoXoKqFKrJkKyoqzFJY/0wUXG8xpKnVTQ8nzS8IH8NncXsgNFZxdJvv8B1LS6lhs13iwh31tB5GSXeQXOGNeSWa4kgGssNsG2Z5No5WASKhZ4DPLhsx3MruD1rJUX8BMRFFiBa90A+V/petc5L54Cx6f7pLbxOFtomYlgPyDoiMOr+azXmAUD43jZIpVC8udgekJsL9Pm5cMl1Mz9rtxQZRxvaToq55VD6yR1lxmah29qUqDQ91W/fC0mGllDDaYkuRkKrcThOK4dYUOU9K+P2L7WVPSTOKkfQUjNUnuQucF1ylafloCLWpjai8dTXa/) is my attempt at it in Paper Sketch. I would expect the logging to happen when I run it.

How can I fire a vanilla JS mouse event that Paper JS will receive?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that there are several things that prevent your example from working:

- `Paper.js` has its own `MouseEvent` class which might be in conflict with native one when used in `PaperScript` context (e.g. in sketch.paperjs.org) so you should work in `JavaScript` directly.
- `Paper.js` click detection relies on multiple events firing (`mousedown` then `mouseup` with some timing and distance checking) so you should use a simpler event (e.g. `mousedown`).

The simplest for you is to try to decline your specific case from a working example.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt3wu02m/) giving you a start point.

```
// Setup Paper.js.
paper.setup('canvas');

// Create an orange rectangle covering all the canvas.
new paper.Path.Rectangle({
    rectangle: paper.view.bounds,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    // On mousedown on this rectangle...
    onMouseDown: function(event) {
        // ...draw a blue circle at event point.
        new paper.Path.Circle({
            center: event.point,
            radius: 30,
            fillColor: 'blue'
        });
    }
});

// On button click...
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // ...trigger a fake mousedown event at point 100,100.
    document.getElementById('canvas').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
        clientX: 100,
        clientY: 100
    }));
});
```